# AngularJS - ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using a ng-click on a ion-item (menu item) to call a function ... but nothing happens , someone help me please!

the ion-item with a ng-click:

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-left item-icon-right" id="menu-list-item4" data-componentid="list-item4" ng-click="signout()">
```

the function on controller:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','$state', "Auth",($scope, $state, Auth) {

     $scope.signout = function() {
     firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
         alert("Signed out successfully");
         $state.go('login');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {

            alert(error.message);
        });
  }
```

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem?

Comment: when i click nothing happens on console ,,,

Comment: What are you expecting to happen on the console?

Comment: alert do not appears , nothing happens .. console should be show me some error to indicate that the function have been called ... you undestood

Comment: Put in a console.log to see if the function has been called. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).